# Access $moment inside async fetch of NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS version 2.12.2.. I am trying to access `$moment` inside async fetch but it is returning **`app.$moment` is not a function**. Below is my snippet:

**pages/_key.vue**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdSign } from '@/constants/encryption.js'

var pickerValue = new Date()
var dTime = pickerValue.getTime()

export default {
  async fetch({ store, params, app }) {
    const theUuid = app.$generateUUID()  // this is a global property
    const theSignature = mdSign({
      uuid: theUuid
    })
    const body = {
      cpKey: params.key,
      day: app.$moment(pickerValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      sign: theSignature,
      time: dTime
    }
    await store.dispatch('example/fetchHistory', body)
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

**plugins/filter.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { translations } from '@/constants/pinyin.js'

const moment = require('moment')
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {
  moment
})
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  ...
  ...
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/filters.js',
    ...
    ...
  ]
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: It appears to me that there is a name mismatch. Your file is `plugins/filter.js` when on your nuxt config you write `plugins/filters.js`. That may also be a copying error but I can't see anything else wrong with your code off the top of my head.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada install it as a new plugin with install method, that will be easy for you to access it from any place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @nuxtjs/moment to your project:

```
npm i @nuxtjs/moment
```

Add @nuxtjs/moment to your nuxt.config.js modules:

```
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/moment'
]
```

There are Nuxtjs specific packages for many of the libraries you would typically use in a Vue app.